# I've solved it by taking modulus of each side. Is there any other possible way to solve this question?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\left(a,b,c,d\right) \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and if $$a+bi=\frac{c}{d+\cos(x)+i\sin(x)}$$

Show that $$(d^2-1)(a^2+b^2) +c^2 = 2acd$$

Comment: What do you mean by "I've solved it by taking modulus of each side"? The modulus of the LHS is easy but on the RHS... (even correcting the second cosine into a sine).

Comment: I have corrected back the second $\cos(x)$ to $\sin(x)$, as it was.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

cross multiplication leads to the equation$$ad+a\cos(x)-b\sin(x)+i(bd+b\cos(x)+a\sin(x))=c$$
your equation is true
writing
$$a\cos(x)-b\sin(x)=-ad$$
and 
$$a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)=-bd$$
squaring both equations and adding we get
$$a^2(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))+b^2(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))=a^2d^2+b^2d^2$$
can you finish?
from this equation we get
$$a^2+b^2=d^2(a^2+b^2)$$ thus $$d^2=1$$ if $$a^2+b^2\neq 0$$